# getting error TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I'm trying to call a function on two buttons

```
nav1or2.navi1.navBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goSmall);
nav4.navi4.navBtn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goSmall);
function goSmall(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
gotoAndPlay(41);
}
```

the second button `nav4.navi4.navBtn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goSmall);` is not working and i m getting this TypeError:

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object
>   reference.

please help.

Comment: Can you show some more of your code? Is `nav4.navi4.navBtn4` on the displaylist when you try to add the listener?

Comment: this is the code only, of if need i can share my file

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it,  instead of using this `nav1or2.navi1.navBtn1`, `nav4.navi4.navBtn4`  now I am using `nav1or2.navi1`, `nav4.navi4` its is working in my case, navBtn4 doesn't have the "addEventListener" but I am not sure why it is not working with this `nav4.navi4.navBtn4` 
if any one know please let me know the url of my file has been changed : http://sdrv.ms/1bo86qQ

Answer (score 0):

That means that navBtn4 doesn't have the "addEventListener" method at the time when you're running that code. Try using the debugger with a break point on that line and checking that whether or not it has been initialised.

Comment: navBtn4 nad navBtn1 are same location, I am sharing my file here, can you please check https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D3E6A39E4DF81F04!967&authkey=!ALX2Dl3DyYiNxzM

click on division button its working here 
but its not working with others

Answer (score 0):

I Found your problem!!!

Fix the code as follows:

```
nav1or2.navi1.navBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goSmall);
nav4.navi4.navBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goSmall);
function goSmall(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    gotoAndPlay(41);
}
```

Your problem is:
navi1
navi2
navi4
etc...
ARE ALL THE SAME OBJECT!!

When you change one of them you change them all!

So They all contains "**navBtn1**" and NOT "**navBtn4**"

Thats why you get Error #1009 because the property "navBtn4" really doesn't exists!!